# How to add two navigation bars on Bootstrap xPage

Tags: css, xpages

Here is my simple xPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
        <xe:navbar id="navbar1" headingText="Navigation Bar" fixed="fixed-top">
        </xe:navbar>
        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:simpleResponsiveConfiguration
                fixedNavbar="fixed-top" invertedNavbar="true"
                collapsedLeftMenuLabel="Menu" collapseLeftColumn="true" navbar="true"
                pageWidth="fixed">
                <xe:this.navbarAppLinks>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode label="App Layout App Link 1"
                        page="AppLinkPage.xsp">
                    </xe:pageTreeNode>
                </xe:this.navbarAppLinks>
                <xe:this.navbarUtilityLinks>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode label="App Layout Utility Link 1"
                        page="UtilityPage.xsp">
                    </xe:pageTreeNode>
                </xe:this.navbarUtilityLinks>
            </xe:simpleResponsiveConfiguration>
        </xe:this.configuration>
    </xe:applicationLayout>
</xp:view>
```

It uses Application Layout Navigation bar. And I want to add another one to put more controls/buttons on it. Second navigation bar should stick to the main one and be page wide. I put Responsive Navigation Bar control into Application layout then set fixedNavbar="unfixed-top" and it looks good except it's not page wide (see #1 on the picture).  If I set fixedNavbar="fixed-top" then it appears over the main Navigation bar (see #2). So how to make second Navigation bar page wide?

[image]

Comment: You need to use CSS. What have you tried already? Have a look at the generated html and the related CSS that affects the navigation bar.

Comment: I just thought there is an easy way to do it by either setting appropriate navigation bar properties or putting the second bar into special place in the app layout. There is not sense to waste a time by using custom CSS for standard control

Comment: I understand and I might be wrong. Perhaps it is possible using configuration options

Comment: OK, then what is the best practice to build two navigation bars? I need a standard one  and another one where I would show some buttons like "Edit Document", "New", "Save" and maybe the document title. The main navbar would contain app info and app links